# Paragraph spacing in latex

Tags: spacing

I want spacing between these two paragraphs but unable to get enough spacing

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Although the more appropriate name for this discrete symmetry transformation
would be “motion reversal”, the term “time reversal transformation” is
so well established that we shall adopt this practice. It should be emphasized
from the outset that the time-reversal transformation does not cause a system
to evolve backwards in time, despite the fact that it includes a change
in the time argument of a state.
(need spacing manually over here say)
One does not need clocks that run
backwards in order to study time reversal and the invariance of a theory
under this transformation. What one is really dealing with is a reversal of
the motion. In quantum mechanics the situation is further complicated by
a formal difficulty: In order to describe time reversal, one needs antiunitary
operators. In this section we first study the time-reversal transformation in
classical mechanics and nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, and then turn
our attention to the Dirac equation.
\end{document}
```

Also I am not sure but I think latex editor s(say I am using tex studio) uses default margin spacing at all sides. I want that during my binding of my report I have enough spacing at left side as the latex default leaves space above.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Not sure what your exact problem  is, but vertical spacing between paragraphs is set by a nonzero value for `\parskip`.  Other than that, your code contains a single paragraph for TeX.  To ensure you have two paragraphs, you need a blank line between both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading package `parskip` and leaving a blank line:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
Although the more appropriate name for this discrete symmetry transformation
would be “motion reversal”, the term “time reversal transformation” is
so well established that we shall adopt this practice. It should be emphasized
from the outset that the time-reversal transformation does not cause a system
to evolve backwards in time, despite the fact that it includes a change
in the time argument of a state.

One does not need clocks that run
backwards in order to study time reversal and the invariance of a theory
under this transformation. What one is really dealing with is a reversal of
the motion. In quantum mechanics the situation is further complicated by
a formal difficulty: In order to describe time reversal, one needs antiunitary
operators. In this section we first study the time-reversal transformation in
classical mechanics and nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, and then turn
our attention to the Dirac equation.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.But i need say more spacing between these two paragraph or say a line.

Comment: You can change the option `skip`, cf. https://ctan.org/pkg/parskip